# Can't locate import javax.inject.Inject package

Tags: java, importerror, dagger

I'm trying to implement Dagger as a dependency injector in an IntelliJ project, but my code is failing on:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
```

Intellij is finding the '`javax`' package, but not the '`inject`' package, so it fails.

I am new to Android, so I apologize if this is a no brainer, but can anyone tell me why the inject package is not being found?

Comment: Make sure you have java EE 6 packages download, alternatively: on intelliJ, you can hit alt+enter and there will be an option such as "search the web for this package" and it will give you a list of jars that have that package.

Comment: When I use IntelliJ to search for jars, it tells me that there are no jars available for 'javax.inject.Inject'.

Comment: Turns out it was a combination of factors:

1.Turn on Annotations in your IntelliJ preferences: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-external-annotations.html

2.Include the inject jars: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject

3.Profit

Answer (score 31):

add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 30):

Dagger depends on JSR 330, the Java standard annotations which are used for dependency injection (think: `@Inject`, `@Singleton`, etc.).

This is a separate jar that you have to include. If you were using a build system with integrated dependency management (Maven, Gradle, Ant+Ivy, sbt) you'd get this for free. If you're still copying around jars then you have to add it manually.

You can download the latest jar from [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.inject%7Cjavax.inject%7C1%7Cjar) (at the bottom).

Comment: You should not, per maven guidelines, ever "get for free" transitive dependencies you are actually using in your own code, so I recommend importing the javax.inject artifact in any case, if you are using its annotations.

Answer (score 9):

Add the inject library directly from Maven like this:

- File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Libraries -> Add -> From Maven
- Search for `javax.inject:javax.inject:1`
- After it's been found click OK

[image]

Answer (score 9):

put to gradle

```
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Answer (score 4):

In case if anyone using plain Java project not Maven or Gradle or e.t.c. You can download a separate Jar file from here [Inject Jar file](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject/1)

and then add to your external libraries, in IDEA you can do that as follows:
File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> New Project Library (+)

Then find the path to library and job is done.

Comment: have you an idea why it is compile with java 8 (don't need to this library) and not for Java 7 ?

Comment: This approach will not scale to real world projects and when working with a team. It is always preferred to use a dependency handling framework like maven or gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI in case someone stumbles in here (like me) who is currently running a (mega) JakartaEE-upgrade-session:

Jakarta EE 10 moved a lot to jakarta-namespace - including `javax.inject` - see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject

The class `Inject` can now be found in the Maven dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.inject/jakarta.inject-api

Answer (score 0):

// dependency injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"

```html
// dependency injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    implementation {
        exclude(group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject')
    }
```

Comment: This caused me so many headaches, This bit of code somehow breaks gradle and results in "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS, JETPACK_COMPOSE, ML_MODEL_BINDING)" and as you can guess, there is close to NONE solutions that I could find and I had to change my gradle version...