# Convert existing SBT Scala application to Play

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka

I've been working on building an application with Akka actors, and now that I've completed the actor-based business logic I'd like to give it a RESTful + websocket front-end. I'm trying to find instructions for how to setup Play within the context of an existing application. The only instructions I could find are how to create new Play applications. Is there any documentation on how to do this?

UPDATE: This question has more to do with the SBT setup than connecting the controllers to my actor based business logic. I tried to modify `build.sbt` and `plugins.sbt` to include the things that activator built when I did `activator new` but IDEA is complaining about `Cannot resolve symbol PlayScala`. Also I am wondering about moving my actors from the SBT-standard `src/main/scala` to `app/` -- should it be in `app/actors` (as I saw in one of the templates) or in `app/models` ?

Here's my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
resolvers += "repo.novus rels" at "http://repo.novus.com/releases/"
resolvers += "repo.novus snaps" at "http://repo.novus.com/snapshots/"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

and here is my `plugins.sbt`:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
```

Comment: `In order to use this layout, use disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)` https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy You may want look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Part is to connect your Businesslayer (actor-based business logic - a ActorSystem) with the Controller ([play.api.mvc.Controller](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Controller)) in the Play MVC.
The following Sample show how to do that:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import akka.actor._
import javax.inject._

import actors.HelloActor

@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  val helloActor = system.actorOf(HelloActor.props, "hello-actor")

  //...
}
```

then you need to know some about the Play Framework:

- The Router translates each incoming HTTP request to an action call (a public method in a controller class).
- The Controller contains some Actions.
- A Action do some work in your Businesslayer (Your Actor System) and Return a Result

Now define some Route Request Paths:

```
- GET   /clients/all          controllers. ... .list()
- GET   /clients/:id          controllers. ... .show(id: Long)
```

And implement the Action in your Controller:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask
implicit val timeout = 5.seconds

def show(id: Long) = Action.async {
  // This ist a ask pattern returns a Future
  // Here ist the Connection between the Action from Play to your
  // Actor System - your Business Layer
  // map it to your own result type
  (helloActor ? SayHello(id)).mapTo[String].map { message =>
    Ok(message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @robert-halter, this is helpful. My questions has more to do actually with the SBT setup, and where I should put my files. The default SBT configuration has my source in src/main/scala, but Play has a different file structure, and it says I should `disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)`. Also I'm confused how to setup my build.sbt and my plugins.sbt. I tried to create a new play app with activator and migrate those changes over into my existing applications build.sbt and plugins.sbt, but IDEA is complaining things like `Cannot resolve symbol PlayScala`

Comment: I edited my plugins.sbt and build.sbt per the instructions here `https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/NewApplication` and I am getting `Cannot resolve symbol` for `Controller` and `Inject` in  your sample code. My build.sbt is not giving me a `Cannot resolve symbol` for `PlayScala` though.

Comment: @SameerParekhBrenn : `play.PlayScala` is a Plugin Name. `Controller` came from `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.9")` -> This can be a Problem in your IDEA IDE. For `Inject` see [Cantt locate Inject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718662/cant-locate-import-javax-inject-inject-package) or [Plugin Example for Actors](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaPlugins)

Comment: @SameerParekhBrenn : For Play 2.4 : The Class `javax.inject.Inject` is in the javax.inject-1.jar

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE Answer:

Start in your Project File the `activator`
Then start the web App with `run`
and open the browser with http://localhost:9000
This loads all the dependencies and compiles the Scala Play Application.

This should correct your IDEA Ide Problems about missing Dependencies.

In Scala Play 2.4 you can choose between to Project Layouts.

- the Project layout `app/`
- the Project layout `src/main/scala` used by SBT and Maven Project is new and experimental and may have issues.

Before (Play 2.3 and smaller)
there where only the Project layout `app/`

The three Packages

```
app/controllers -> Application controllers
app/models -> Application business layer
app/views -> Templates
```

are predefined.

You can of course add your own packages, for example an `app/actors` package.

Answer (score 0):

The below changes to the project helped me to adopt PlayFramework (version:2.8.1) into the existing project:

1. In `plugins.sbt` add 
   `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.1")`
2. In `build.sbt` add the below to `libraryDependencies`:
   `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % playVersion`

   2.1: Add `guice` support in the `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(guice)`

   2.2: Add the below to include `/src` to classpath:
   `unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "src"`
3. Add the `/src` directory to add it to classpath and verify:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/training/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project coursera-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/training/IdeaProjects/coursera/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to coursera (in build file:/home/training/IdeaProjects/coursera/)
[info] * /home/training/IdeaProjects/coursera/app-2.12
[info] * /home/training/IdeaProjects/coursera/app
[info] * /home/training/IdeaProjects/coursera/app
[info] * /home/training/IdeaProjects/coursera/src
```

PlayFramework expects the following:

1. `controllers` in `app/controllers` - Add your controller.scala here
2. `application.conf` in `conf`
3. `routes` in `conf` - Add a route that refers to controller on step-1

Execute: `sbt run`

Reference: [The official repo](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/project)