# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I tried adding dagger to my project by adding
`implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"` (based on answer of Liubomyr Protsyk in: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718662/cant-locate-import-javax-inject-inject-package))

in build.gradle and It resulted with "Could not get unknown property 'dagger2Version' for root project ..." which I understand, what I cannot understand is why after removing that line I cannot sync gradle project... Every try to use "try again"
[image]

results in:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert string value 'UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS, JETPACK_COMPOSE, ML_MODEL_BINDING)
```

any ideas how to fix that? I honestly have no clue, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out:   
Github - https://github.com/google/dagger  
Maven - https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.dagger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone has the same error, you need to update Android Studio  to the latest version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Defining `dagger2Version` as extras before trying to access it may help:

```
project.ext.set('dagger2Version', '2.40.5')
```

And the getter also seems to be wrong:

```
rootProject.ext.get('dagger2Version')
```

Comment: "Cannot get property 'get' on extra properties extension as it does not exist"

Comment: and also, I don't think implementing dagger correctly will fix the "UNIFIED_TEST_PLATFORM" error